# Mac Catalyst - Make window NSToolbar transparent

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, uikit

## Problem

Hi All,

I need help to make my window NSToolbar transparent, however, I still need to be able to use a toolbar within the window scene titlebar. Currently, you can set a titlebar to be transparent by either hiding your toolbar or not having one at all, but even though I will not be adding any actual tools within the toolbar, there needs to be one so that I can reposition the window traffic light buttons using the UITitlebarToolbarStyle property - I know that from Electron 8, developers are able to reposition the traffic light buttons (is this also possible in Swift?)

Any help is much appreciated

[image: MacOS (Mac Catalyst) titlebar]

**Current Code**
*- this is situated within the AppDelegate*

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1366 * 0.9, height: 1024 * 0.9)
if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
    let customToolbar = NSToolbar()
    titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
    titlebar.toolbar = customToolbar
    titlebar.toolbarStyle = .unified
    titlebar.autoHidesToolbarInFullScreen = true
}
#endif

window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
window?.windowScene = windowScene
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

## Solution

I was able to work out how to make the titlebar transparent - it will however require you to install a library called [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic). This library allows you to access private hidden APIs for MacOS apps  because...

> *"Apple only made a very small portion of the macOS AppKit API visible to Catalyst apps"*

To edit the transparency of the toolbar within MacOS Catalyst, follow these instructions - you should only need to do the following within your SceneDelegate file.

**(1)** Outside your Scene Delegate, add the following (make sure that the Dynamic library is installed). SPM: https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic.git

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
import Cocoa
import Dynamic

extension UIWindow {
    var nsWindow: NSObject? {
        var nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(self)
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            nsWindow = nsWindow.attachedWindow
        }
        return nsWindow.asObject
    }
}
#endif
```

**(2)** Inside your SceneDelegate, add the following lines of code within the delegate method that connects your scene to the window...

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) { [self] in
    windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1366 * 0.9, height: 1024 * 0.9)
    if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
        titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
        titlebar.toolbar = NSToolbar()
    }
    
    let nswindow = Dynamic(window?.nsWindow)
    nswindow.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    nswindow.backgroundColor = Dynamic.NSColor.clearColor
}
#endif

window?.windowScene = windowScene
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Final Code**

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
import Cocoa
import Dynamic

extension UIWindow {
    var nsWindow: NSObject? {
        var nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(self)
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            nsWindow = nsWindow.attachedWindow
        }
        return nsWindow.asObject
    }
}
#endif

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) { [self] in
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1366 * 0.9, height: 1024 * 0.9)
            if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
                titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
                titlebar.toolbar = NSToolbar()
            }
            
            let nswindow = Dynamic(window?.nsWindow)
            nswindow.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            nswindow.backgroundColor = Dynamic.NSColor.clearColor
        }
        #endif

        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

## Extra ✨

If you want to hide (or disable) the window traffic light buttons, you can access them with `nswindow.standardWindowButton(x)`, where 'x' represents the traffic light button you want to edit. For example...

```
let nswindow = Dynamic(window?.nsWindow)
nswindow.standardWindowButton(0).isHidden = true //close
nswindow.standardWindowButton(1).isHidden = true //minimise
nswindow.standardWindowButton(2).isHidden = true //expand
```

Comment: Just checking in case you have found a way to make NSToolbar transparent in Mac Catalyst. At least on Ventura it always has a grey-ish background I cannot change it no matter what's color is behind it.

Comment: @ggould75 - I was able to work out how to make the toolbar transparent. I have added the solution above as well as an extra note. Hope you find it helpful.